# Angular2 use Skycons JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have problem implementing [Skycons](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) in my Angular 2 app. I have installed Skycons via `npm i skycons`.

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module 'skycons'
```

**weather.component.ts** (part that is responsible for Skycons)

```
import * as Skycons from 'skycons';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

ngOnInit() {
    this.todayDate();
    this.getWeather();
    this.findLocation(52.4069200, 16.9299300);

    var skyconType = function (icon) {
      if (icon === 'rain')
        return Skycons.RAIN
      else if (icon === 'snow')
        return Skycons.SNOW
      else if (icon === 'sleet')
        return Skycons.SLEET
      else if (icon === 'hail')
        return Skycons.SLEET
      else if (icon === 'wind')
        return Skycons.WIND
      else if (icon === 'fog')
        return Skycons.FOG
      else if (icon === 'cloudy')
        return Skycons.CLOUDY
      else if (icon === 'partly-cloudy-day')
        return Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY
      else if (icon === 'partly-cloudy-night')
        return Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT
      else if (icon === 'clear-day')
        return Skycons.CLEAR_DAY
      else if (icon === 'clear-night')
        return Skycons.CLEAR_NIGHT

      return Skycons.CLOUDY
    }

    jQuery(function () {
      var skycons = new Skycons({ "color": "#111" })

      jQuery('.skycon canvas').each(function (i, elem) {
        skycons.add(elem, skyconType(elem.className))
      })


      skycons.play()
    })
  }
```

**weather.component.html** (part that is responsible for Skycons)

```
<div class="skycon">
          <canvas width="84" height="84" id="icon" class="{{   weather.currently.icon }}">{{  weather.currently.icon }}</canvas>
        </div>
```

`{{  weather.currently.icon }}` returns for example "`partly-cloudy-day`"

---

This is the first time i am using external JS libraries in Angular app.

In Developer Tools i get two errors (no errors during Angular compilation):

> jQuery.Deferred exception: skycons.add is not a function TypeError: skycons.add is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: skycons.add is not a function

Versions of software:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.4.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 2.4.10
```

If you need me to post more code just ask.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for displaying Skycons in an Angular app? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Hadh Hi, yes i did, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
const Skycons = require('skycons')(window);

 $(document).ready(function () {
  const skyconType = function (icon) {
    if (icon === 'rain') { return Skycons.RAIN; }
    else if (icon === 'snow') { return Skycons.SNOW; }
    else if (icon === 'sleet') { return Skycons.SLEET; }
    else if (icon === 'hail') { return Skycons.HAIL; }
    else if (icon === 'wind') { return Skycons.WIND; }
    else if (icon === 'fog') { return Skycons.FOG; }
    else if (icon === 'cloudy') { return Skycons.CLOUDY; }
    else if (icon === 'partly-cloudy-day') { return Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY; }
    else if (icon === 'partly-cloudy-night') { return Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT; }
    else if (icon === 'clear-day') { return Skycons.clear_day; }
    else if (icon === 'clear-night') { return Skycons.clear_night; }

    return 'cloudy';
  };
  $(function () {
    let skycons = new Skycons({ 'color': '#3C4858' });
    $('.skycon canvas').each(function (i, elem) {
      skycons.add(elem, skyconType(elem.className));
    });
    skycons.play();
  });
});
```